# Clustering zip data at state level

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, clustering, experiment-design

**[image: Dataset]**

**Problem :**  Recomment 2 markets (States) for A/B test

**Solution tried :**

1. Cluster rows based simply by ZIP codes but then each state could appear across multiple clusters. How do I then dedup the results? If I am able to dedup the states, how would I go about ranking based on the given features?
2. Group data by STATE and gather results for features X1, X2, X3, this way I have a distribution **(Have atmost 250 records for each of 33 states)**. I then tried to assess distribution of each feature for each store using KS test.

**Questions :**

1. Should I perform pre-processing steps differently i.e instead of entire columns should I use group of states? (Currently std scalar scikit-learn and use clustering)
2. Is clustering the correct idea for partitioning data and recommend market?
3. How do I proceed with 2 and in 1, are my steps correct?

Comment: It sounds like you want to find two similar states and have people/zipcodes/entities in one assigned to receive treatment and the people/zipcodes/entities in the other state be assigned to control experience. Is there a reason why you cannot use more than one state as a control? What decision does this experiment help you make?

Comment: That is accurate.  Conversion rate to evaluate media channels.

Comment: The popoulation stats have been aggregated at ZIP level. Budget I believe is what restricts the design to just 2 states.